# WPF ListView - How to get column aligment to work properly with resizable columns?

Tags: wpf

I did some googling on the this found several references which did similar things to the example below. When I try this, the first column is aligned right initialy.
Without the setter for HorizontalContentAlignment the text stays put when the column is resized instead of tracking the right edge of the column. Adding the setter has the effect of centring the TextBlock in the column as it is resized but it does not stretch to fit the column. I changed the background colour of the first column to hightlight what is happening. I am using VS 2008 with version 3.5 SP1 of the framework.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="CharacterData">
        <x:XData>
            <Data xmlns="">
                <Character First="Bart" Last="Simpson" />
                <Character First="Homer" Last="Simpson" />
                <Character First="Lisa" Last="Simpson" />
                <Character First="Maggie" Last="Simpson" />
                <Character First="Marge" Last="Simpson" />
            </Data>
        </x:XData>
    </XmlDataProvider>
</Window.Resources>

<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CharacterData},
  XPath=Data/Character}" >

    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="First Name" >
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Width="98" Margin="-6,0" TextAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding XPath=@First}" Background="Aqua" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="Last Name">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Width="100" Margin="-6,0" TextAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding XPath=@Last}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

**Update:** Removing the width parameter from the TextBox allows the stretching defined in the ItemContainerStyle to work properly.

```
<DataTemplate>
   <TextBlock  Margin="-6,0" TextAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding XPath=@First}" Background="Aqua"  />
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put `HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"` onto your listview.

**Update**: I meant the list view itself, not the container style:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CharacterData}, XPath=Data/Character}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
```

**Update2**: I just noticed that you have set the `Width` of your text blocks - that's why they are not stretching. Remove the `Width` and replace it with `MinWidth` if you want a minimum width

Comment: Forgot to add the setter for HorizontalContentAlignment which also appears in most of the examples I saw - have updated my question. It has some effect - the text block centres in the column rather than staying put but does not stretch to fill the space.

Comment: I tried this also with and without the setter on the ItemContainer style, doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Good spot - taking out the width attribute does the trick, but the setter for ItemContainerStyle is still needed. This example show that the power of WPF comes at a price - there a lot of moving parts which iteract with each other. However from what I've read this isn't the best designed control. Several things like this which should be straight-forward are not.